# Exporting phpmyadmin query as csv - problems (not a duplicate)

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

Before anyone says this is a duplicate, I havent found this case anywhere.

1. I make my query (a joined query with 4 tables) and then hit EXPORT, but it exports just the table and not the query with the combined info and not just the fields I asked for but ALL the fields of the first table in the query.  So basically, the query is ignored at the export stage.
2. I have loooked into "INTO OUTFILE" however, I do not have the right access to access the file after it is created.
3. I wonder if "INTO OUTFILE" can save files elsewhere? (remotely, I mean)
4. I wonder if the amount of results (6200( is straining the server?

My code :

```
SELECT pname, concat(afname, ' ', alname) as artistname, pubname, pwide, phigh, concat(pubcode,'-',psku) as fullsku, catname, concat('/prints/', pubcode,'-',psku, '.jpg') as imagesource, ptext FROM (prints LEFT JOIN publishers ON (publishers.pubid=prints.ppub) LEFT JOIN artists ON (artistid=partist)) LEFT JOIN cats ON (pcat = catid) WHERE psku <> '' AND phigh > 0 ORDER BY pubname,ltrim(alname),ltrim(afname) LIMIT 6200
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, when hitting the "export" button at the bottom of my query results, phpmyadmin exports one of the tables, not the query results. I can't figure why. My workaround is to create a new table, adding

```
CREATE TABLE xxxx AS
```

before my select query, and then export this new table.

Comment: Just a thought, could you create a view from the query and export that?

Comment: Yes, I can. Instead of `create table xxx as` I can do `create view xxx as` and then export this view. Still, it is only a workaround, and it takes some more time than it would if I were able to export the query result straight ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't heard anything, I will post my very lame workaround but at least I got what I wanted.

I did a copy/paste into BBEdit and then tidied up the data with a series of find/replaces.

Not ideal and not the quickest solution, but it worked where nothing else would.